# I don't understand how this code works. Write a code that prints the sum of the first n(input) natural numbers

Tags: python, loops

```
# Write a code that prints the sum of the first n(input) natural numbers.
n = int((input("Enter The Value: ")))
s = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    s += i
print(s)
```

I figured out the code but I can't understand how this code works. Please help me.

I am confused about how this code works.

Comment: What is it exactly that you do not understand? Please be more precise.

Comment: i didnt understand how this whole code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go line by line:

`n = int((input("Enter The Value: ")))`

Variable `n` is assigned to the value entered by the user converted to integer

`s = 0`

Variable `s` is assigned to value `0`

`for i in range(1,n+1):`

This is a loop on a range of numbers that will go from number `1` until the number passed by the user plus one. I suppose your understanding problem is here.

The second parameter of `range` is the **exclusive** stop value, meaning that if the user pass `5`, the range will be `range(1,5)`, meaning it will range between 1 to 4.

`s += i`

Here you're incrementing the value of variable `s`.

`print(s)`

Print the value of variable `s`.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, there is no need to sum all the numbers one by one (complexity O(n)). You should use some basic math instead:

```
n = input('Enter the value: ')
result = n * (n + 1) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line

```
n = int((input("Enter The Value: ")))
```

asks the user for a value and converts it to integer. Then, you set the variable `s` to 0. Then you loop through all the values from 1 up to the number that was inserted, and for each iteration you add to `s` the value of the number you are iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume n = 5.
s=0 right?

```
for i in range(1,n+1): -> n+1 is now 6... 
  s += i -> meaning... 0=0+1 -> 1=1+2 -> 3=3+3 and so on until i is n+1(6).
```

because `i` always go on one more and s keeps climbing as well.
the result of s will be in this case = 15